# css3 centering the div with dynamic content

Tags: html, css, alignment

i am developing a mobile HTML5 page with css3, i am having the page like below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Starter page</title>
        <style>
            .float-right{float:right}
            .float-left{float:left}
            .clear{clear:both}
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="content" id="home">

            <div class=" ">
            <!--START: Div to be centered to page-->
                <div class="DivToBeCentered">
                    <div class="float-left">
                        <!--START: This paragraph content is dynamic from database, i want to center align the div with the class 
                                    DivToBeCentered with reference to its parent-->
                        <p class="">dynamic para 1 with background image</p>
                        <!--END: This paragraph content is dynamic from database, i want to center align the div with the class 
                                    DivToBeCentered with reference to its parent-->
                    </div>
                    <div class=" float-left">
                        <p class="">static para 2 without background image</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            <!--END: Div to be centered to page-->
            </div>

    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to horizontally center align the div with the class "DivToBeCentered" in the code above to its parent div. Inside that div there are two paragraph tags,for one paragraph tag content is dynamic, so its width may change while loading the page, how do i center align the that div with the class "DivToBeCentered" to its parent. it will be more helpful for me if you solve this, i got stuck in this issue for the day.Thanks in advance

Comment: can you specify the width of the div you want to center ?

Comment: The Width of the div is dynamic, since the paragraph tag inside the div to be centered is having the content which is coming from database.

Comment: give a min width to that div. & apply margin: 0 auto;

Comment: @SVS i give like that as you suggested it is not working, now i tried in firefox.element.style {
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-width: 10px;
}

Comment: @MohamedHussain! ya! something like this.

Comment: @SVS thanks for ur suggestion, i tried it is not working.

Comment: Can you provide a mokup image of what you want?

Comment: see the demo I have provided in my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simple solution will be `display: inline-block;` to the `DivToBeCentered` and `text-align:center;` to the `outer` div

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ekupeb/3/)**

**Css to be changed**

```
.outer {text-align:center;}
.DivToBeCentered {display: inline-block;}




<html>
    <head>
        <title>Starter page</title>
        <style>
            .float-right{float:right}
            .float-left{float:left}
            .clear{clear:both}
          .outer {text-align:center;}
          .DivToBeCentered {display:block-inline}
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="content" id="home">

            <div class="outer">
            <!--START: Div to be centered to page-->
                <div class="DivToBeCentered">
                    <div class="float-left">
                        <!--START: This paragraph content is dynamic from database, i want to center align the div with the class 
                                    DivToBeCentered with reference to its parent-->
                        <p class="">dynamic para 1 with background image</p>
                        <!--END: This paragraph content is dynamic from database, i want to center align the div with the class 
                                    DivToBeCentered with reference to its parent-->
                    </div>
                    <div class=" float-left">
                        <p class="">static para 2 without background image</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            <!--END: Div to be centered to page-->
            </div>

    </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<div class="content" id="home">
        <!--START: Div to be centered to page-->
            <div class="DivToBeCentered">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <!--START: This paragraph content is dynamic from database, i want to center align the div with the class 
                                DivToBeCentered with reference to its parent-->
                    <p class="">dynamic para 1 with background image</p>
                    <!--END: This paragraph content is dynamic from database, i want to center align the div with the class 
                                DivToBeCentered with reference to its parent-->
                </div>
                <div class=" float-left">
                    <p class="">static para 2 without background image</p>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        <!--END: Div to be centered to page-->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.content{
  position: relative;
}

.DivToBeCentered{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  /*for vertical centering*/
  /*
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  */
  margin: auto;
}
```